# Apache returns 403 forbidden after 1 mins

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403, wildfly-8

I have a Java EE application running on Wildfly and I use Apache as Proxy Server.

One of my requests takes more than one minute to respond. When I use directly Wildfly it returns, but if the request goes over Apache, I take 403 forbidden after 1 minute. I have done some research but I couldn't find a proper solution.

Probably there is a configuration file for this. As I have seen, it is not in httpd.conf :).

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Default ProxyTimeout is 60 second in Apache. With

```
ProxyTimeout 600
```

on virtual-host configuration I have solved the problem.